# Splitting two sets

Tags: c#, linq, algorithm, data-structures

Given 2 collections of elements, S1 and S2, what is the most efficient way to compute 3 sets (A, B, C), where A is the unique elements of S1 and B is unique elements of S2 and C is common items of S1 and S2.

Comment: nope! just a learning exercise.

Comment: no problem, it's just that the rules of StackOverflow state that homework should be marked with the "homework" tag. I was just asking since your question seemed like a nice exersice for homework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can find out here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546153.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Or, in code:

```
var C = S1.Intersect(S2).Distinct()
var A = S1.Except(C).Distinct()
var B = S2.Except(C).Distinct()
```